# Automatically Increment Vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

Hey so I'm working on using vlookup to import a very large amount of cells, and I'm trying to figure out how to  increment the row. Basically I need to lookup every 4 cells from top to bottom. For example, the first 3 Cells would be as such

```
=VLOOKUP('V:\folder1\folder2\f3\f4\f5\[ID5-EqVolVarAnn.xlsx]Liability.VarAnn'!$B$3:$F$50000,1,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP('V:\folder1\folder2\f3\f4\f5\[ID5-EqVol-VarAnn.xlsx]Liability.VarAnn'!$B$7:$F$50000,1,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP('V:\folder1\folder2\f3\f4\f5\[ID5-EqVol-VarAnn.xlsx]Liability.VarAnn'!$B$11:$F$50000,1,FALSE)
```

How can I make it increment automatically? Do I need to go into vba and use a loop?

Comment: Where is the lookup value?

Comment: What is the reason for incrementing every 4 cells. Are you trying to ignore conditions?

Comment: Use an `indirect` function combined with an `IF` or `countif` to do the increments.